# What if the toolbar does not reach the top of the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I needed to change Action Bar to Toolbar. The fact is that there is space between the state line and Toolbar space remains. Can you tell me what to do? I'll provide the code if it need.

main

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

This code I wrote in MainActivity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar) 
getSupportActionBar().setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
[This is my screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWIxx.png)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyEPM.png)
```

Comment: Would be better if you rich you question with code an even a middle image of that space. Provides all the information thinking like a person that don't know your code.

Comment: Please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Code been added

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the below to get what you actually wanted

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

      <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <!-- Your Remaining code for the rest of your layout -->

      </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It will let your toolbar to be on top.

Comment: It doesn't help, the problem remains.

Comment: The white space between Status Bar and Toolbar remains